# Facebook iOS SDK publish post with - feeling excited, etc

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if it is possible to publish post to user's wall with " - feeling excited" or " - with TagFriend". I search in the documentations but didn't find any way to do that.

I was posting the status this way:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithCString:szMessage encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"message"];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if ( error ) {
        NSLog( @"post error: %@", [error localizedDescription] );
        if ( pObject != NULL && failCallback != NULL ) {
            (pObject->*failCallback)();
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"post id: %@", result[@"id"] );
        if ( pObject != NULL && successCallback != NULL ) {
            (pObject->*successCallback)();
        }
    }
 }];
```

Does anybody know of a way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you've found a solution for that?
Maybe they have it in their new SDK? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the USER_ID/feed documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

You can specify a friend tag by using the "tags" property. However, you can only specify "tags" if you also specify the "place" property.

There's no API for the "feeling excited" emotions.